# Why I cannot use the option "MathOutput"?

Tags: html

I'm on Windows 8.1 with Mathematica 9.

```
Export["test.html",EvaluationNotebook[],"MathOutput"\[RightArrow]"GIF","CSS"->None]

Export["test.html",EvaluationNotebook[],"CSS"->None,"MathOutput"\[RightArrow]"GIF"]
```

> Export::argt: Export called with 4 arguments; 2 or 3 arguments are expected. >>
>
> Export::noelem: MathOutput[RightArrow]GIF is not a valid set of export elements for the HTML format. >>

I think picture is clear to show the problem.

[image]

`"CSS" -> None, "MathOutput" \[RightArrow] "GIF"` are options? right? and order sensitive?

`"CSS" -> None` seems to be an argument? of course it's an option in the help page of HTML,

Comment: Why do you post your code as an image? You should know better than to do that by now. I think it is just laziness. To save yourself the work of converting your code and results to markdown, you put the burden of typing it in on anyone who wishes to help you. That's rude.

Comment: @m_goldberg I've added the necessary code in the last line? Is that not enough? The warnings and NotebookObject will not look good in SE!

Comment: @m_goldberg Here, I've made such mistakes, so sad. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30900/how-can-i-convert-an-input-cell-to-text-cell

Comment: @m_goldberg well, is the question not so clear? I'm confused by the downvotes...

Comment: Thanks for adding the code in markdown. I evaluated it on my system using V9.0.1 on OS X. I do not get the error you show. Instead I get `Export::noelem: MathOutput\[RightArrow]GIF is not a valid set of export elements for the HTML format.` This indicates you can't  export a `Manipulate` as a GIF.

Comment: I've retracted my down vote. It was for not inserting the code as markdown.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks and also for testing, Maybe next time I should put my markdown codes in the beginning of the question...haha

Comment: @m_Goldberg "MathOutput"->"GIF" is listed as an option in the HTML doc page, though.

Comment: Export of HTML files seems to be thoroughly broken in V9.0.1 on OS X. Even something as simple as `Export[
 FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", test.html"}], Plot[Sin[t], {t, -6, 6}]]` produces a bad HTML file.

Comment: @m_goldberg Works OK on my Mac and v9 (after quoting the file name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 7 this line appears to work correctly:

```
Export["test.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "MathOutput" -> "GIF", "CSS" -> "None"]
```

I think the problem is that `\[RightArrow]` is *not* an option and you need `\[Rule]` or `->`.

Comment: Works OK for me,  Mac OS X running Mathematica v 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think: if you type `\[RightArrow]` it converts to hex code **2192**; if you type "->" and let Mathematica convert it for you, it converts to hex code **f522**.

[image: two arrows]

Or, as the manual says:

> \[RightArrow] - Not the same as \[Rule]

Comment: cormullion, are you on-line right now, and you you have a few minutes?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm on an iPad at the moment...

Comment: Okay.  I needed someone to run some code.  Thanks for replying.